# Is one hour enough for changing planes in Newark?

Tags: transit, short-connections, connecting-flights, ewr

I am coming from Miami and will change planes at Newark, my final destination is Beijing. I only have 1 hour from arriving to departure, is that enough time or must I have change to an earlier departure from Miami?

Comment: As usual with such questions: are the two flights on the same ticket/booking, or where they booked separately? Do you have checked luggage? What airlines/flights and/or what terminals?

Comment: 1 hour sounds too close for comfort just about anywhere to me

Comment: I would not try this short a connection even if booked on a single ticket with no checked luggage.

Comment: Is there an additional flight from Newark to Beijing after your flight?  In that case you can risk, and hope for a seat on second flight. Closing door on long haul flights are often 45 minutes before departure (+ 15 minutes to choose if remove baggage or not, you will not have baggage on board, so they will not wait for you.)

Answer (score 5):

If this has been booked as a single ticket than

1. It's a legal connection that meets the minimum connection time
2. Statistically you have an ok chance of making it, if all goes well.
3. If things do not go well and you miss it, the airline will book you on the next available flight for free. However, that my be a day later.

If these are two separate tickets, you will NOT make this connection.

There are a few things that can help speed things up

1. Make sure you check in for both flights and getting boarding passes for both segments.
2. Familiarize yourself with the airport layout and map. Figure out which gates these flights arrived the day before and check how you would get from the arrival to departure gate. If you are flying United, most likely you'll arrive and depart from Terminal C
3. Newark is a huge airport and the distances between gates are quite long. If you have any mobility issues, call the airline right now.
4. Not checking luggage helps